# Change list bullets in org-mode depending on embedding level

Tags: org-mode, faces

Is it possible to change the face of list bullets dynamically, mimicking the behaviour of WYSIWYG textprocessors like MS Word?

[image]

Comment: You cannot change them in the buffer (parsing requires that the bullets are fixed), but you can certainly overlay any symbol you want: that just changes the display without changing the text of the buffer. See e.g. this [thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-06/msg00183.html) in the ML.

Comment: I think the `org-bullets` package does something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following NickD's advice, I've changed the look of list bullets using overlays:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 '(("^[[:space:]]*\\(-\\) "
        (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "•"))))))
```

Furthermore, I've increased the indentation offset in order to emphasize the degree of embedding:

```
(setq-default org-list-indent-offset 4)
```

I'm happy with the result, even though it's not exactly what I was looking for in my question:

[image]

**COMMENT:**

Of course, with this approach, one could get closer to the intended look with the following:

```
(setq-default org-list-indent-offset 4)

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 '(("^\\(-\\) "
        (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "•"))))))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 `((,(concat "^[[:space:]]\\{" (number-to-string (+ 2 org-list-indent-offset)) "\\}\\(-\\) ")
        (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "◦"))))))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 `((,(concat "^[[:space:]]\\{" (number-to-string 
                                (* 2 (+ 2 org-list-indent-offset))) "\\}\\(-\\) ")
        (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "▸"))))))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 `((,(concat "^[[:space:]]\\{" (number-to-string 
                                (* 3 (+ 2 org-list-indent-offset))) "\\}\\(-\\) ")
        (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "▹"))))))
```

[image]

But this presupposes that the indentation is accurate in terms of the number of spaces. The best solution would be to make the font-lock depend on the logical embedding level using something like `(org-list--depth (org-element-at-point))`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the package [org-superstar-mode](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode). Previously there was another package [org-bullets](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) which is no longer maintained. This seems to be the successor.